# Angular chart from Chart.js

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I want to draw charts in angularjs , using chart.js which is under MIT license. I would prefer to use like,

Could someone please refer me a working example so that i can study and change it according to need.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a tutorial? At a glance, it seems there are several already available.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following Demo using the **`angular-chart.js`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
  <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
        </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bravo !! It worked.  Thanks for such quick response.